# Can't recover Storage Taken By Linux Deploy

Tags: root-access, 4.4-kitkat, linux

I used the Linux Deploy app to install Linux on my phone using root Access. It seems to make a partition on my device to install Linux which took up some storage on my Phone.  Now I want to recover that storage but I find no option in the app.  Uninstalling it also does not help.

Comment: Sorry but it is not clear which app you were using. When talking about third party apps always include a link to the app, best to Google Play Store. In general your device seems to be rooted, so you can delete the Linux partitions and resize the user data partition using the common Linux tools.